# Swift iOS update Chart with data from Database

Tags: ios, json, swift, database

I am currently learning how to connect to a SQL DataBase and displaying the information. I also am trying to grasp closures at the same time as well as building charts. So far I can successfully pull the data from the database then display the information in a `UITableViewController`.

I have a simple `UIViewController` with a `UIView` to display the data. So far my issue is all the data is pulled inside of the closure, but then when I do anything outside of the closure there is no data.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!

    var sensorReadings: [SensorReadings] = []

    var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "replaced with actual URL ")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { print(error!); return }

            if error != nil {
                print("Datatask Error: ", error!)
            } else {
                do {
                    if let sensorData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:String]] {
                        for sData in sensorData {
                            let dataId = sData["dataid"] ?? ""
                            let readingTime = sData["readingtime"] ?? ""
                            let sensorId = sData["sensorid"] ?? ""
                            let reading = sData["reading"] ?? ""

                            self.sensorReadings.append(SensorReadings(dataId: dataId, readingTime: readingTime, sensorId: sensorId, reading: reading))
                        }
                    }                    
                } catch {
                    print("Serialization Error ", error)
                }
            }
            }).resume()

        // Creates an array of strings to hold reading values
        var tempArray: [String] = []

        // Loops through the downloadaed data
        // Adds each of the readings to tempArray
        for reading in self.sensorReadings {
            tempArray.append(reading.reading)
        }

        // Convert String to Double
        let doublesArray = tempArray.compactMap(Double.init)

        // Chart Information
        for i in 0..<doublesArray.count {
            let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: doublesArray[i])

            self.lineChartEntry.append(value)
        }

        let line = LineChartDataSet(entries: self.lineChartEntry, label: "Number")
        line.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]

        let chartData = LineChartData()
        chartData.addDataSet(line)

        self.lineChartView.data = chartData

        self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "Data"

    }
```

First am I on the right track with getting the data from the database? Then how is it that I can update the Chart with the information? How to I return the information from the URLSession? Or is there a way I can update the chart like I do in a `UITableView1:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this article: 
https://stablekernel.com/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-swift-closures/

I gotten a bit more understanding. As I didn't know what retain cycle was. Still going to read up but using shoan's answer and tweaking with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.updateChart()
}
```

This worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem here.
The problem is you have the code to update the table in viewDidLoad immediately after you call your api using URLSession.
You need to wait for the response from the api.
Try the following

```
 @IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!

var sensorReadings: [SensorReadings] = []

var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "replaced with actual URL ")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { print(error!); return }

        if error != nil {
            print("Datatask Error: ", error!)
        } else {
            do {
                if let sensorData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:String]] {
                    for sData in sensorData {
                        let dataId = sData["dataid"] ?? ""
                        let readingTime = sData["readingtime"] ?? ""
                        let sensorId = sData["sensorid"] ?? ""
                        let reading = sData["reading"] ?? ""

                        self.sensorReadings.append(SensorReadings(dataId: dataId, readingTime: readingTime, sensorId: sensorId, reading: reading))
                        self.updateChart()
                    }
                }                    
            } catch {
                print("Serialization Error ", error)
            }
        }
        }).resume()
}
fun updateChart()
{
    // Creates an array of strings to hold reading values
    var tempArray: [String] = []

    // Loops through the downloadaed data
    // Adds each of the readings to tempArray
    for reading in self.sensorReadings {
        tempArray.append(reading.reading)
    }

    // Convert String to Double
    let doublesArray = tempArray.compactMap(Double.init)

    // Chart Information
    for i in 0..<doublesArray.count {
        let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: doublesArray[i])

        self.lineChartEntry.append(value)
    }
    let line = LineChartDataSet(entries: self.lineChartEntry, label: "Number")
    line.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    let chartData = LineChartData()
    chartData.addDataSet(line)
    self.lineChartView.data = chartData
    self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "Data" }
```

Let me know if it works.
Also there is a retain cycle. User [weak self] inside the closure.

Comment: This didn't work. When I run it, it first shows no chart data, then when I click on the view with the chart it brings up a blank chart with out any information. Then I get a blue warning stating: UI API alley from background thread. Then that expands into: UIView.setNeedsDisplay() must be used from main thread only.

Comment: I figured it out. Check my answer. Definitely a step in the right direction and using terminology I wasn't familiar with, I looked it up and was able to move on.

Comment: Good to know you figured it out. I hope I could be of any help. Happy coding.